# Using an old PC case and power supply as a HDD Enclosure?

Tags: power-supply, external-hard-drive, enclosures

I have 5 HDD and my computer is not handling the situation very well. hehe

There are some towers that I can buy to put 4 of my drives out, but I'm thinking that I could use the power source of a failed computer I have and use it to power the 4 (or at least 3) of the drives. The data cables (SATA) will remain connected to the working computer (so no USB solution).

The problem is that the power source will not work unless it is connected to the failing computer motherboard. Is there any way I could use the power source without plunging it to the old motherboard?

Any "HOW-TO" links may be useful as well.

Comment: I got it running :) I put 3 HDDs inside an empty PSU case (useless PSU), in which actually fit very well, with its fan (which I adapted to use the HDD power connector). I left open one of the sides (for connection cables) and used the old (but working) small PSU (170 Watts) with the clip trick. It works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. Plugging in the power cable into the motherboard connects the required pins together that enables the SMPS to turn on. I dont know the exact pins but I gues you can google it out: use a insulated wire stripped at both ends to connect the pins together; the SMPS fan will start running if you do it correctly.

Comment: Yes, actually they were the green and the black :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found what I was looking for:

http://aphnetworks.com/lounge/turn_on_psu_without_motherboard_the_paperclip_trick

But any other options/alternatives are welcome :)

Comment: If your current enclusure allows it, why dont you buy an SMPS with a higher rating?

Comment: That's other alternative... I normally don't use 4 of the 5 HDD all the time, so I thought I could save some energy if I just turn them on when I need them. So if I can also recycle the old PSU its better, don't you think?