# Using a separate power supply for an external drive array

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply, power

I'd like to add an external 4 or 5 bay drive enclosure ([example)](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=605&area=en) to expand the storage capacity of my NAS, an HP Microserver Gen8. I'll use a 4-port SATA PCIE expansion card in the NAS to provide the additional SATA ports, but the existing power supply won't be able to power the additional drives, so I'm hoping to use a regular ATX power supply, say 300W, with a manual switch to [bridge the PowerOn and Gnd wires](http://www.gideontech.com/content/articles/196/1). This will power the drives as well as the built-in fan in the enclosure.

Similar questions have been asked before ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/240272/using-an-old-pc-case-and-power-supply-as-a-hdd-enclosure) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/638494/can-i-use-a-second-power-supply-for-hard-drives)) but the answers don't address my particular concern: if all or most of the drives power-down during idle, will this:

1. Trigger the under-current protection of the power supply, turning it off? This could cause data loss in a worst case scenario.
2. If it continues to run, will this damage the power supply? Presumably the total load of 5 drives on standby and a 80mm fan would be very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use an ATX PSU to power the drives up.

1. Hot start the PSU by connecting green wire to any black wire (like you linked).
2. Connect your drives.

That's it. Nothing else is needed. There are no problems whatsoever with this kind of setup. The PSU will not self-shutdown. I used something like this many times. I had 16 drives connected at a point, 8 internally and 8 with additional PSU. The uptime of this setup was around 3 months and I had no problems.

Note that drives won't power-down on idle by themselves; that's dictated by the OS and for it to actually work in theory the orange control wire is needed, but even if that happens, there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks @Overmind. I intend to configure drives to power-down when idle, and I suspect all will be in standby at some points in time. Computer power supplies are switched-mode power supplies and require some load at all times in order to operate. Is the load of the enclosure's fan, plus 5 drives in standby, going to be enough? If not, the under-current protection of the supply is likely to kick in and switch it off. I realise I could just avoid any problem by configuring the drives to never spin down, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Yes, it should be enough. But note that making the drives stand by and wake up a lot is more damaging to them compared to constant continuous operation.

Comment: Confirmed that the ATX power supply I'm using (cheap old thing, about 300W) works fine with only a standby load. Even switches on without any devices connected, although I haven't tested running it like that for an extended period.

Comment: Should be fine on long term.